# объявление переменных в mySQL выпадет с ошибкой

Tags: mysql

при попытке объявить переменную

BEGIN
DECLARE idNewPlayer INT;
END

сервер возвращает ошибку:
...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE idNewPlayer INT;

во всех попадающихся мануалах ничего не нашел, что бы намекнуло, почему нельзя объявить переменную

Comment: DECLARE разрешено только внутри составного оператора BEGIN ... END и должно стоять в его начале перед любыми другими операторами. Невозможно по вашей строке определить, соблюдается ли это правило.

P.S. А вообще мне кажется, что это спам-пост, ведущий на абсолютно бесполезную станицу. забитую рекламой по самое не хочу.

Comment: пробовал и BEGIN
DECLARE @i Int;
END результат тот же...
насчет рекламы, извиняюсь, просто попался ресурс на котором можно чтото проверить

Comment: Я очень надеюсь, что ваш ПОЛНЫЙ код выглядит как-то так:


`DELIMITER $$`

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcedure()`
`BEGIN`
 `DECLARE idNewPlayer INT;`
`END$$`

Comment: да, суть такая же. 
но если бы не появилась указанная ошибка не дергал бы народ по пустякам )

Comment: Вы можете выложить ПОЛНЫЙ код, чтобы не приходилось бы загадками и намёками руководствоваться?

Comment: спасибо, 
то ли лишний пробел после BIGIN мешал, то ли луна в третьем доме ) да и найденный ресурс с проверкой синтаксиса, увел мои поиски не в том направлении